# Matlab Ros Extract Point Cloud 2 BLOB

Tags: matlab, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Matlab with ROS support, and I'm successfully reading PointCloud2 data from a Kinect. How can I extract the x,y,z,rgb data from the BLOB structure contained in the *sensor_msgs/PointCloud2* message?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190346/matlab-ros-extract-point-cloud-2-blob/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2014-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The message contents are binary encoded, so Matlab doesn't know how to extract the data.

If you want to implement it yourself, you can take a look at how ROS does it in the read and write functions:
https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/indigo-devel/pcl_ros/include/pcl_ros/point_cloud.h
http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html

In the short term, it may be a lot easier for you to work with the depth image instead, as Matlab has all sorts of image processing/decoding functions.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1